# Knitr R : Grouping multiple plots in to HTML

Tags: r, knitr

I am very new to Knitr and I am trying to do the following in a R markdown file.

I have a set of names, for each name I make two plots. I need to get a HTML file  for each name, containing the respective plots.

`{r, echo=FALSE}
for name in setofNames{
barplot(xx)
barplot(yy)
}`

I am quite lost on how to do this. Does any one have any ideas?

EDIT:
I am able to generate different HTML files now for each name, using stitch(). However, I don't get all the plots, the code I've retains only the last iteration. I've also explored the opts_chunk() feature, but in vain. It probably has something to clear the cache with, but I am not sure.

Below is the piece of code:

```
for name in setofNames{
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, fig.keep='all', fig.show='asis')
fname=paste(name,".html")
stitch_rhtml("../testSub.r",output=fname,envir=globalenv())
}

===testSub.r file===
barplot(xx)
barplot(yy)
```

Would appreciate some inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a "control" file that calls `knitr` several times (once per name). Each time `knitr` processes the same `Rmd`-template but with different data.

In the code below I exploited the fact that `knitr` by default uses the objects in the calling environment (see `?knit`: `envir = parent.frame()`). Hence it is possible to modify an object in the "control" file and a subsequent call of `knitr` will use that object when processing the template.

(Of course, global variables could be avoided. Then, the control file would need to assign objects in a specific environment and pass this environment to `knitr`.)

The "control" file (`control.R`) could look like this:

```
library(knitr)

## Generate data
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(
  name = sample(x = LETTERS, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  value = rnorm(n))

## knit the template once per "name"

lapply(X = levels(dat$name), FUN = function(name) {
  currentSubset <- dat[dat$name == name, ]
  knit2html(input = "template.Rmd", output = sprintf("output_%s.html", name))
})
```

`template.Rmd`:

````
```{r}
op <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(currentSubset$value, col = "green", main = name)
plot(currentSubset$value, col = "red", main = name)

par(op)
```
````

This generates a separate HTML file (`output_[Letter].html`) for each letter in `levels(dat$name)`.

Note that each call to `knit2html` overrides the plots in the `figure` directory. However, this does not matter because the HTML files do not reference external figures but *contain* the figures in data URIs. This is due to `markdown::markdownToHTML()` which is called from `knitr::knit2html()`:

> Any local images linked using the <img> tag will be base64 encoded and included in the output HTML.

(Source: [markdownToHTML](https://rforge.net/doc/packages/markdown/markdownToHTML.html))

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In my edit, I do something very similar. And so, my HTML files get generated with new names. But, in the figure folder produced by knitr, the figures are named like "testSub-Rhtmlauto-report-1.png", "testSub-Rhtmlauto-report-2.png" and so on. I need a way to override this file naming. Because, for each iteration, it seems to be overwriting the default file name.

Comment: Why do you care about the contents of the `figure` folder? True, the code in this answer also overrides the files in `figure` but I don't see a problem with this because the HTML files display the right figures (stored in data URIs), no matter what's in `/figure`.

Comment: Because, I see the same images [corresponding to the last iteration] in all the HTML files generated. That's why I thought, may be it has to do something with the naming of the files in the figure folder. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The problem you describe is related to the naming of the files, yes. But do you refer to the approach that you edited into the question or the the solution in this answer? For the latter you should see the correct figures, no matter what happens to the files in the figure folder. Have you checked that?

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at the wrong output directory. Your method work liked a charm. Thank you so much. Thumbs up for the knit2html.

Comment: @Siva No worrys, happy to help. As this seems to be your first post on SO: 1) Welcome! 2) If you are satisfied with an answer, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Done. Didn't know about that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the par function to get what you need. Also, I usually remove the "echo=FALSE" because it messes up my knitted html.

http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html.

Here is an example of text that gets entered together for the knitr:

````
```{r}
df<- replicate(100, runif(n=20))
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for (i in 2:7) hist(df[,i],main=colnames(df)[i])
```
````

Let me know if you need more specific help and I'll edit this post.

Comment: How could `par()` help with "a HTML file for each name"? Your advice combines two plots into one plot.

Comment: Works fine for me when I enter the par first and enter the two lines of text together                                                                                      par(mfrow=c(2,3))
> for (i in 2:7) hist(df[,i],main=colnames(df)[i])

Comment: @ephackett: Thanks for your inputs. Your example lets me only combine the plots, but not generate different HTML. I wish to generate, different HTML files for each name [each HTML will just have two plots].

Comment: Ah, sorry. Looks like someone else got answered it though!